# Where does vim store custom key mapping cache?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I've installed a plugin via vundle, and later decided to remove it. I've run `vim +BundleInstall +BundleClean +q` and I'm quite sure everything related to this plugin is removed from `.vimrc` and `.vimrc.bundles`.

However, even after I restart, when I type `:map` in vim, I can still see the key mappings for this particular plugin, and invoking them caused `Unknown function` error in Vim.

I'm wondering if vim keeps a cache of custom key mappings somewhere else that I should clean up after removing a plugin?

Comment: You can find out where the maps are coming from via `:verbose map`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @peter-rincker, using `:verbose map` I realized some of the functions/key bindings are store in `.vimviews`. Remove that direcotry and problem solved!

Comment: Saving sessions and views is great but it leads to too many issues when you are tinkering with your setup. Be careful with that.